# how to extract the utm_content from the URL in SQL bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to extract the utm_content from the URL.

For example:

https:/www.xxxxxx.com/br/pt/yyyyy/example?origin=ALL&destination=ALL&utm_source=salesforce&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=just_an_example_ok&utm_content=**I_would_like_just_this_part_of_the_string**

¿How could I extract just the utm_content after the *utm_content=*?

Generally, there is  12-13 fragments (splited by _) in my utm_content.

I would like to have this:

| URL | utm_content |
| --- | --- |
| https:/www.xxxxxx.com/br/pt/yyyyy/example?origin=ALL&destination=ALL&utm_source=salesforce&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=just_an_example_ok&utm_content=I_would_like_just_this_part_of_the_string | I_would_like_just_this_part_of_the_string |

Any suggestions?

Comment: mysql or bigquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See example below

```
select url, 
  regexp_extract(url, r'utm_source=([^&]+)') as utm_source,
  regexp_extract(url, r'utm_content=([^&]+)') as utm_content
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It worked as I expected.